# AutoCompleter in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

as you can see from the image I am with this problem.

[Link Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/6xkk.png)

In OnItemClickListener dell'autocompleter should I fill the data in the other EditText, some contained in other movies.
If I use this function:

```
private OnItemClickListener codListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rigaprodotto_old, parent, false);

        setProdotto((Prodotto) Controller.getElement(Controller.PRODOTTI,
                id, 0, 0), v);
    }
};
```

I take references to a view but then when I

```
public void setProdotto(Prodotto p, View parent) {

    AutoCompleteTextView codCompleter = (AutoCompleteTextView) parent
            .findViewById(R.id.autoCompleterOrdineArticoloCodNew);
    EditText unitaEdit = (EditText) parent
            .findViewById(R.id.editTextOrdineArticoloUnitaNew);
    EditText ivaEdit = (EditText) parent
            .findViewById(R.id.editTextOrdineArticoloIvaNew);
    EditText acciseEdit = (EditText) parent
            .findViewById(R.id.editTextOrdineArticoloAcciseNew);

    ....
    codCompleter.setText(p.codice);
    ivaEdit.setText("22");
    unitaEdit.setText("1");
    acciseEdit.setText("0.54");
    ....

}
```

to fill the cell did not display anything on the screen and the other EditText I remain empty.
It seems that I do not take the right reference dell'AutoCompleter.
 ..
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you could have an ontextchanged listener in which on aftertextchanged() to set the values of the edittext with what you want.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply the problem is not intercepting the basic changes in the text, the problem is that, for example, to 'OnClick a result, the program should put the text nell'autocompleter (this works with the codAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter) but not allows me to fill in the other cells with the values ​​that I want ..